# jQuery hotkey plugin does not work for single characters (from a to z)

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

This is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2QEdS/

I use this piece of JS code to do the hotkeys: https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/blob/master/jquery.hotkeys.js

However, it works with keys like <kbd>f4</kbd>, but does not work like<kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>. Can someone help to take a look? The code in the jsfiddle is:

```
/*
* jQuery Hotkeys Plugin
* Copyright 2010, John Resig
* Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
*
* Based upon the plugin by Tzury Bar Yochay:
* http://github.com/tzuryby/hotkeys
*
* Original idea by:
* Binny V A, http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/
*/

/*
* One small change is: now keys are passed by object { keys: '...' }
* Might be useful, when you want to pass some other data to your handler
*/

(function(jQuery){

jQuery.hotkeys = {
version: "0.8",

specialKeys: {
8: "backspace", 9: "tab", 10: "return", 13: "return", 16: "shift", 17: "ctrl", 18: "alt", 19: "pause",
20: "capslock", 27: "esc", 32: "space", 33: "pageup", 34: "pagedown", 35: "end", 36: "home",
37: "left", 38: "up", 39: "right", 40: "down", 45: "insert", 46: "del",
96: "0", 97: "1", 98: "2", 99: "3", 100: "4", 101: "5", 102: "6", 103: "7",
104: "8", 105: "9", 106: "*", 107: "+", 109: "-", 110: ".", 111 : "/",
112: "f1", 113: "f2", 114: "f3", 115: "f4", 116: "f5", 117: "f6", 118: "f7", 119: "f8",
120: "f9", 121: "f10", 122: "f11", 123: "f12", 144: "numlock", 145: "scroll", 186: ";", 191: "/",
220: "\\", 222: "'", 224: "meta"
},

shiftNums: {
"`": "~", "1": "!", "2": "@", "3": "#", "4": "$", "5": "%", "6": "^", "7": "&",
"8": "*", "9": "(", "0": ")", "-": "_", "=": "+", ";": ": ", "'": "\"", ",": "<",
".": ">", "/": "?", "\\": "|"
}
};

function keyHandler( handleObj ) {
if ( typeof handleObj.data === "string" ) {
handleObj.data = { keys: handleObj.data };
}

// Only care when a possible input has been specified
if ( !handleObj.data || !handleObj.data.keys || typeof handleObj.data.keys !== "string" ) {
return;
}

var origHandler = handleObj.handler,
keys = handleObj.data.keys.toLowerCase().split(" "),
textAcceptingInputTypes = ["text", "password", "number", "email", "url", "range", "date", "month", "week", "time", "datetime", "datetime-local", "search", "color", "tel"];

handleObj.handler = function( event ) {
// Don't fire in text-accepting inputs that we didn't directly bind to
if ( this !== event.target && (/textarea|select/i.test( event.target.nodeName ) ||
jQuery.inArray(event.target.type, textAcceptingInputTypes) > -1 ) ) {
return;
}

var special = jQuery.hotkeys.specialKeys[ event.keyCode ],
// character codes are available only in keypress
character = event.type === "keypress" && String.fromCharCode( event.which ).toLowerCase(),
modif = "", possible = {};

// check combinations (alt|ctrl|shift+anything)
if ( event.altKey && special !== "alt" ) {
modif += "alt+";
}

if ( event.ctrlKey && special !== "ctrl" ) {
modif += "ctrl+";
}

// TODO: Need to make sure this works consistently across platforms
if ( event.metaKey && !event.ctrlKey && special !== "meta" ) {
modif += "meta+";
}

if ( event.shiftKey && special !== "shift" ) {
modif += "shift+";
}

if ( special ) {
possible[ modif + special ] = true;
}

if ( character ) {
possible[ modif + character ] = true;
possible[ modif + jQuery.hotkeys.shiftNums[ character ] ] = true;

// "$" can be triggered as "Shift+4" or "Shift+$" or just "$"
if ( modif === "shift+" ) {
possible[ jQuery.hotkeys.shiftNums[ character ] ] = true;
}
}

for ( var i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++ ) {
if ( possible[ keys[i] ] ) {
return origHandler.apply( this, arguments );
}
}
};
}

jQuery.each([ "keydown", "keyup", "keypress" ], function() {
jQuery.event.special[ this ] = { add: keyHandler };
});

})( this.jQuery );

jQuery(document).bind("keyup", "f4", function(){
    alert("f4");
})

jQuery(document).bind("keyup", "a", function(){
    alert("a");
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: i'm having the exact same problem right now.  did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You could just add "a" to the specialKeys object. I've added it here and it seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/2QEdS/1/

```
specialKeys: {
8: "backspace", 9: "tab", 10: "return", 13: "return", 16: "shift", 17: "ctrl", 18:     "alt", 19: "pause",
...
220: "\\", 222: "'", 224: "meta", 65: "a", 66: "b"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is fixed in this fork:

https://github.com/YuppY/jquery.hotkeys

This pull request would fix it in the original project

https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys/pull/31

Comment: PR has been merged into the original project now https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys